# Python / Creating a class for my turtle object

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am new to programming and I have recently written my first game in Python. That is a simple game without any user input. Just 5 turtles that are moving from left to right going from 1 to 5 pixels (used randint) at single frame.

For now each turtle is written like showed below:

```
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t2.penup()
t2.color("Red")
t2.shape("turtle")
t2.setpos(-400,100)
t2.pendown()
```

I wanted to create a class for that but I'm stuck with that:

```
class Trt():
    def __init__(self,color,posit,shape):
        self.object = turtle.Turtle()
        self.penup()
        self.color = color
        self.shape = shape
        self.posit = posit
        self.pendown()


t1 = Trt("Yellow", (-400, 200), "Turtle")
```

The error that appers is the the one below. That makes me think that the issue is with generating the turtle object.

> AttributeError: 'Trt' object has no attribute 'penup'

Many thanks in advance!

Rafal

Comment: extend Turtle. `class Trt(turtle.Turtle):`

Comment: I've tried that but anorther error appeared:

AttributeError: 'Trt' object has no attribute '_drawing'

Comment: self.object = turtle.Turtle() ??

Comment: init the super class

Comment: can you also attach the super class?

Answer (score 2):

do something like this:

```
import turtle

class Trt(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self,color,position,shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()
        self.color(color)
        self.shape(shape)
        self.goto(position)
        self.pendown()

t1 = Trt("Yellow", (-400, 200), "turtle")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up two concepts - member objects and class inheritance. Your `Trt` class can either have a *member* that is a `turtle.Turtle` object (as you implemented it), and then you would need to access all operations on that member through the member path. E.g., pen-up would need to be:

```
self.object.penup()
```

Alternatively, you can make `Trt` a derived class of `turtle.Turtle`. If you do that, you can access the pen-up functionality (as well as others), directly as:

```
self.penup()
```

If you choose to implement `Trt` as a derived class, do not forget to properly initialize the base-class object, by calling its `__init__` method from within `Trt.__init__`.

Deciding whether you want an object member or a derived class is done base on whether the `Trt` class is just an enhanced kind of `turtle.Turtle` - in which case it should be a derived class, or has multiple different functions, which mill prioritize using a member object.